# emacs as CLI to transform strings

Tags: yasnippet

Is it possible to use emacs as just an CLI tool to transform some strings? What I want is to use yasnippet to generate file by template. I use emacs, but my team doesn't and it would be nice to have only one template that can be maintain by team.

Comment: Based on the question as-is, Emacs might not be the right tool for the job. The question is very context dependent and requires more detail

Comment: Yeah, maybe you are right. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `--script` command line option is what you need. You can also use the following shebang line :

```
#!/path/to/emacs --script
```

To directly execute the file itself. Note that the `message` function prints strings to `stderr`.